# ( Beginner ) If variable selenium on python

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, variables

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to learn webpage automation with Selenium.

So far I have managed to open a webpage, make it click where I want it to click and input any words I want. However, I'm struggling with the if variable.

Basically I want to tell Selenium to click a button that I located by xpath. In turn this button should display a new element on the screen that I can also locate by xpath. However, sometimes when I click this button the new element doesn't display. So how can I tell Selenium that if the element doesn't display it should refresh the page and click until the new element is displayed and only then it can click on the new element?

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = "https://www.compumsa.eu/item/GV-R55XTOC-4GD-Gigabyte-Radeon-RX-5500-XT-4GB-OC-PCIE-9320"

driver.get(url)

driver.maximize_window()

click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_LBAddItem"]')

click.click()

itempanier = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SpanCaddy"]')


if (itempanier.is_displayed()
```

Comment: Please show us whatever code you've. it will help us more to give you advise/solution.

Comment: of course there you go : https://prnt.sc/1tsun13

Comment: It's hard to read from an image, try updating your question with code in text format.

Comment: Check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4046632

Comment: My bad i edited my question

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Explicit waits.
2. Use while infinite loop, and inside use `try - except` with `find_elements`, basically `find_elements` will return a **list** in `Selenium-Python` and check for it's size if `>0` element will be visible if not, go to else block and reload the page and this will be repeating until it breaks from the while loop.

break only on two **conditions** :

1. If the if block condition is satisfied or some some reason code has gone into except block.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.compumsa.eu/item/GV-R55XTOC-4GD-Gigabyte-Radeon-RX-5500-XT-4GB-OC-PCIE-9320")
click = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolderMain_LBAddItem")))
click.click()

while True:
    try:
        itempanier = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="SpanCaddy"]')
        if len(itempanier) > 0:
            print('Meaning SpanCaddy web element is visible')
            # do some stuff like clicking on it and then break from the loop. 
            #break
        else:
            print('Meaning SpanCaddy web element is not visible')
            # do some other stuff like reload
            driver.refresh()
    except:
        print('Something went wrong')
        pass
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me i will try that right away

Comment: Sure let me know how it goes, also I could not locate `//*[@id="SpanCaddy"]` but since you have mentioned `in turn this button should display a new element on the screen that i can also locate by xpath,` I thought you'd be able to locate from your end.

Comment: i'll keep working on it thanks